# How to check fragment is visible in Activity OnBackpressed

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity, onbackpressed

How to check fragment is visible in Activity OnBackpressed

I want to check when user click back button in Searchfragment I want to set OnBackpressed is running ,but if user click back button in OtherFragment I want to set OnBackpressed is not running.

and I try this in Activity is not work

```
 btn_back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                SearchFragment searchFragment = new SearchFragment();
                if (searchFragment.isVisible()){
                    onBackPressed();
                }

            }
        });
```

thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, when you declare something like this:

```
SearchFragment searchFragment = new SearchFragment();
```

And then call

```
searchFragment.isVisible()
```

This will obviously return `false` since you didnt even add it to the container. What you need to do is to retrieve the fragment instance that you already added and check it's state.

I have once tried to use the method `isVisible()` but it is not entirely accurate, at least not for my case. What I came up with is to check the top fragment in the container as follow:

```
Fragment fragment = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);
if(fragment instance of SearchFragment) //means your visible fragment is the SearchFragment
    onBackPressed();
```